# cell into rows latex

Tags: tables

I wanat to divide a cell into rows , how do I do that in latex
I need  this result how do I do It

%This will change the font for all the tables in the document.

```
       \documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

%This will change the font for all the tables in the document.
\makeatletter


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\columncolor{Gainsboro}}c}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\centering
\caption{Methodologies Summary}
  \begin{tabular}{|Y|c|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
    \hline
   \multicolumn{1}{|c}\emph{\textbf{Approach}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\emph{\textbf{Feature}}} & Grüninger-Fox  & KACTUS  & METHONTOLOGY & SENSUS & On-To-Knowledge & cyc & Usdhold - King \\
      \hline 

 {Development Process}   & {Project management processes } & \multirow{3}{*}{}   &  &  &  &&  \\
    \cline{1-8}
    & Ontology development-oriented processes  & 
         &          &          &            &            &    \\
          \cline{1-8}
    & Integral processes & 
         &         &          &            &            &  \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

That is where I am At  at the script I don't know how to continue 
[image]

Comment: There are hundreds of posts explaining this very topic. Please search around a bit, prepare a first try and we will be happy to help you with certain problems which might remain. As a hint: You are searching for `\multirow`.

Comment: I did , shall I  edit the post with where I am at at the script

Comment: Please, make table icture such, that columns head become visible. And it seems that your table is rather huge. Probably you need to consider to rotate it to landscape orientation.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
It seems that you expected that someone make this table from scratch for you ... I give below *only a start point* how to make table yourself. Therefore from your new image in question I consider only few table rows. The column heads are still based on guessing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
        \usepackage[table]{xcolor}         
%\makeatletter %doesn't work
%\g@addto@macro{\table[ht]}{\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont}
%\makeatother

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% <-- new
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \centering
\caption{Methodologies S}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|*{7}{C{0.6cm}|}}
    \hline
\multicolumn{10}{|l|}{Approach: Development Process}         \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}
    &   \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\thead{Methodology}}            \\
      \cline{4-10}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\thead{Feature}}
    & aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & f f f & ggg \\
      \hline
\multirowcell{3}{Project\\ management\\ processes}
    &  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{initiation}
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &                           \\ 
      \cline{2-10}
    &  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{monitoring and control}
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &                           \\
      \cline{2-10}
    &  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Management}
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &                           \\
      \hline
\multirowcell{4}{Ontology\\ development-\\oriented\\ processes}
        &   \multirowcell{2}{Development\\ proces}
            &   requirements process   
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &                           \\
      \cline{3-10}
        &   &   design process
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &                           \\
      \cline{3-10}
        &   &   implementations process
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &                           \\

    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\label{ch7:tab:experiencesinpracticalphysics}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I use some new packages: `makecell` for column headings (macro `\thead`) and multi row cells (macro `multirowcell`), `multirow` for support of `makecell` package for ˙multirowcell`and`tabularx`, from which is used column type`X`for multi line cells with self-calculate width. Last seven columns are based on`p{6mm}`type column (redefined into`C` with centering cells content).

Since it seems that table is wide than text width, probably it be sensible to make it in landscape orientation (I haven't any idea about last seven columns with, selected 6mm is pure speculation).

Comment: what I want is to reproduce the  image as table using latex .  I edited the script again , I 'll explain , the feature column is devided into 2 column , project managment  should have 3 rows in the  empty column  next to her .

Comment: @MunaAr, image of table and your code sniped differ a lot. Please, edit your question and based on my code complete your code sniped to Minimal Working Example (with document class which you use, all necessary package and text which should appear in columns heads). Then I and others will be able to help you in improving your table.

Comment: Iam a newbie and I m stuck there i don't know how to divide the rest of the columns into rows

Comment: I suggest you to star read some documentation about LaTeX. For general knowledge see https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf, specifically for table see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. After then the design of tables should be more easy ...